# how, if a value is passed to a textbox from ajax on success, then how to use that value with sql where clause

Tags: php, jquery

[ CODE UPDATED ]

how, if a value is passed to a textbox from ajax on success,  then how to use that value with MySQL where clause?

Ajax Code :

```
var recstr1 = "Ramesh Kumar";
data={txtname:recstr1};
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getprojectnamerep.php',
  data: data,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
    $("#txtname").html(data);
  },
  error: function(data){ alert("Something went wrong !"); }
});
```

Mysql query :

```
<?php $name = $_POST['txtname'];
select * from customer where custname = '$name';
```

When I run this code and check on "Elements"  in Chrome browser it shows the value like this :

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" class="form-control" readonly="" name="txtname">Ramesh Kumar</input>
```

whereas it should show like this :

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" class="form-control" readonly="" name="txtname" value="Ramesh Kumar">
```

Since the value is not coming in value='' that is why var_dump() is returning blank.

Where I am wrong, Please guide and help?

getprojectnamerep.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
    $rpname = $_POST['txtname'];
    echo $rpname;
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you share the PHP source code of `getprojectnamerep.php ` !?

Answer (score 0):

Change some of your js code

```
var recstr1 = "Ramesh Kumar";
data={txtname:recstr1};
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getprojectnamerep.php',
  data: data,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
    //$("#txtname").html(data);
    **$("#txtname").val(data);**
  },
  error: function(data){ alert("Something went wrong !"); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to set the value for text box you need to use `val()`

try this:

```
$("#txtname").val(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`$("#txtname").val(data);` instead of `$("#txtname").html(data);`

Here is the fault.

```
var recstr1 = "Ramesh Kumar";
data={txtname:recstr1};
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'getprojectnamerep.php',
  data: data,
  datatype: "html",
  success: function(data){ 
    console.log(data);
    // $("#txtname").html(data);
    $("#txtname").val(data);
  },
  error: function(data){ alert("Something went wrong !"); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already tried that. var_dump() is returning blank.And in "element" syntax is shown like this :  <input type="text" id="txtname" class="form-control" readonly="" name="txtname">

Comment: Join this for more help - [click](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166113/room-on-question-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-49063257-multiple-developers)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtname').html('something');   // this will put "something" in innerHTML

$('#txtname').val('something');  // this will set the VALUE attribute 
                               //   of the input to "something"
```